# How to get minecraft status?

Tags: python, protocols, response, minecraft, status

What's wrong? I recieve nothing. I have also tried with other Minecraft-servers.

```
import socket
from struct import pack, unpack

host = socket.gethostbyname("localhost")
port = 25565

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

packet = ""
packet += pack('i',4)
packet += pack('p',host)
packet += pack('H',port)
packet += pack('i',1)
s.send(packet)
print s.recv(1024) # Recv nothing ?
```

Comment: u are sending and receiving in same script?

Comment: Yes im sending and after sending receving in this script.

Comment: this will not work, you have to send in one script and receive in antoher

Comment: No.. This sends a packet to a other script/Minecraft Server. And receives response after.

Comment: Sending and receiving port are same? and have u check `Minecraft Server` will surely send data?

Comment: Yes. I Have connected with Minecraft. And it sends data.

Comment: on same port `25565` ?

Comment: Yes the server is open on 25565

Comment: Please confirm that the sending terminates (e. g. add a `print "foo"` after the `s.send(packet)`).  Maybe sending already hangs?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is wrong :

```
packet += pack('p',host)
packet += pack('H',port)
```

Replace with this :

```
packet += pack('p',port)
packet += pack('H',host)
```